# Are we anonymous against governments?

Tags: blockchain, privacy, government

If all transactions are public knowledge and coins are identifiable and thus traceable. With the power of subpoena can't a government uncover who bought the coin(s) from an exchange. It might be unlikely but this appears to be a big hole in claim that bitcoins are an anonymous currency. Or do I misunderstand the technology?

Comment: @Lohoris There's good info there but everyone is focusing on securing a single transaction not the coin history and more broadly exchanging coins to other currencies. Example: If a government sees a coin go to a known "bad" address then to an exchange. They can then subpoena the exchange and the "bad" person is caught.

Comment: yes, that is a known fact.

Comment: This is true, but likely criminals would find ways of laundering like they do with conventional fiat currencies - something like shared send (https://blockchain.info/wallet/send-shared) comes to mind.

Comment: @GeorgePearce Great link, I'm frustrated that kind of anonymity isn't built in but glad to know about that